# WPF UniformGrid dynamic content

Tags: c#, wpf, view, grid, uniformgrid

I have a uniformgrid which i want to dyanmically show contents/view.
It can show either 1, 2, 4, or 6 contents. I set my uniformgrid row, col binding, and the content visibility binding.
This does NOT work in the case of views/contents,
but it DOES WORK in the case for rectangles. Why is that?
How do i modify it to work with views/contents.
Sample **MainWindow.xaml** code.....

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" Content="1" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="2" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="4" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="6" />
    </ComboBox>

    <!-- NOT CORRECT, SHOWS 6 ITEMS ALWAYS -->
    <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding ScreenRows}" Columns="{Binding ScreenCols}">
        <local:ScreenView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Visibility="{Binding VisibleScreen[0]}" />
        <local:ScreenView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding VisibleScreen[1]}" />
        <local:ScreenView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Visibility="{Binding VisibleScreen[2]}" />
        <local:ScreenView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Visibility="{Binding VisibleScreen[3]}" />
        <local:ScreenView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding VisibleScreen[4]}" />
        <local:ScreenView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Visibility="{Binding VisibleScreen[5]}" />
    </UniformGrid>

    <!-- OK, SHOWS 1,2,4, or 6 RECT DEPENDING ON SelectedIndex -->
    <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding ScreenRows}" Columns="{Binding ScreenCols}">
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Red" Visibility="{Binding VisibleScreen[0]}" />
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Orange" Visibility="{Binding VisibleScreen[1]}" />
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Fill="Yellow" Visibility="{Binding VisibleScreen[2]}" />
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Green" Visibility="{Binding VisibleScreen[3]}" />
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Blue" Visibility="{Binding VisibleScreen[4]}" />
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Fill="Violet" Visibility="{Binding VisibleScreen[5]}" />
    </UniformGrid>

</StackPanel>
```

Basically, i have a combobox. If I select 1, my ViewModel will dynamically change rows=1, cols=1, with 1st content Visible, and others collapse. It works in the case for Rectangles, but NOT views. Why is that? How to fix it so that it works for views?

Anyone curious, here is the code (Prism MVVM) in **MainWindowViewModel**

```
class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private const int SCREEN_MAX = 6;

    private int screenRows = 1;
    public int ScreenRows
    {
        get { return screenRows; }
        set { SetProperty(ref screenRows, value); }
    }

    private int screenCols = 1;
    public int ScreenCols
    {
        get { return screenCols; }
        set { SetProperty(ref screenCols, value); }
    }

    private Visibility[] visibleScreen = new Visibility[SCREEN_MAX];
    public Visibility[] VisibleScreen
    {
        get { return visibleScreen; }
        set { SetProperty(ref visibleScreen, value); }
    }

    private int selectedIndex;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return selectedIndex; }
        set 
        { 
            SetProperty(ref selectedIndex, value);
            ChangeScreen(selectedIndex);                    
        }
    }

    private void ShowScreens(int num_screens)
    {
        // make all collapse
        for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_MAX; i++)
            VisibleScreen[i] = Visibility.Collapsed;

        // show only X num screens
        for (int i = 0; i < num_screens; i++)
            VisibleScreen[i] = Visibility.Visible;

        RaisePropertyChanged("VisibleScreen");
    }

    public void ChangeScreen(int idx)
    {
        switch (idx)
        {
            case 0: ScreenRows = 1; ScreenCols = 1; ShowScreens(1); break;
            case 1: ScreenRows = 1; ScreenCols = 2; ShowScreens(2); break;
            case 2: ScreenRows = 2; ScreenCols = 2; ShowScreens(4); break;
            case 3: ScreenRows = 2; ScreenCols = 3; ShowScreens(6); break;
        }
    }
}
```

The **ScreenView.xaml**

```
<UserControl...>
    <!-- SOME HOW IT IS THIS DATACONTEXT CODE MESS UP THE UI -->
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ScreenViewModel x:Name="vm"/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>TEST</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Sample Output

[image]

As you can see from sample output, my combo selection is 1, so it should display 1 TEST, while 1 square is showing which is correct. But why should it show me 6 TEST? How to make it display 1 TEST?

Here's a corect output

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial value of `selectedIndex` is 0 (default value of int field). But content of VisibleScreen array is not matching selectedIndex - you need to call ChangeScreen during initialization, e.g. like this:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Btw,`Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` have no effect in UniformGrid. UniformGrid arranges items in the order they are added

Don't set DataContext inside UserControls.

instead of `Visibility[]` create collection of ScreenViewModel of in MainWindowViewModel (`ObservableCollection<ScreenViewModel>`).

Add `bool IsVisible` property in `ScreenViewModel`.

Change ShowScreens method like this:

```
private void ShowScreens(int num_screens)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_MAX; i++)
        VisibleScreen[i].IsVisible = i < num_screens ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Change the view:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VisibleScreen}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding ScreenRows}" Columns="{Binding ScreenCols}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <local:ScreenView Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}"/>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

ItemTemplate will create a local:ScreenView for each item in VisibleScreen collection AND assign it to DataContext of local:ScreenView

Comment: No Ash, it didn't work. I added your suggestion and still the output is the same. When i change the index in combobox, it still shows all 6 TEXT on screen. If i select 1, i expect 1, not 6.

Comment: @Tim, I can't reproduce that

Comment: I cant figure it out. i still have this issue. Is it possible you share your solution to me?

Comment: " Is it possible you share your solution to me" - I created new WPF project in VS, copied code from question and replaced `SetProperty` with PropertyChanged invokations, because I didn't import Prism packages. that's all. Project targets .net 4.5.2

Comment: Ok, i found the problem. In my ScreenView.xml i also have this

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ScreenViewModel x:Name="vm"/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

But why would this code mess the UI up??? its very standard to have this and i need it for my view model to do some bindings.

Comment: `{Binding VisibleScreen[0]}` is not resolved in `local:ScreenViewModel`, that is why. it is different datacontext

Comment: @Tim. see edit. ItemsControl and ObservableCollection are the way to go. they are very common combo in WPF

Comment: i'll give this a try first thing in the morning, will let you know. thanks alot!